# how to know alpine version abouut openjdk:8-jre-alpine

Tags: docker

This is my docker build file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

MAINTAINER jiangxiaoqiang (jiangtingqiang@gmail.com)

ADD soa-user-service/build/libs/soa-user-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /root/soa-user-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD script/start-docker.sh /root/start-docker.sh

EXPOSE 11004
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/root/start-docker.sh"]
```

now I want to make sure the alpine version to know if it solve the dns problem.what is the alpine version of openjdk:8-jre-alpine?How to know it?Is there any way to specify the alpine version?

Comment: Here is the "from" image dockerfile: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/dd54ae37bc44d19ecb5be702d36d664fed2c68e4/8/jre/alpine/Dockerfile  as you can see it's alpine 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by `dns problem` but the alpine-version can be check login inside the container and run: `cat /etc/alpine-release`